# How to resolve "Unable to import 'requests'pylint(import-error)" in Visual Studio Code IDE?

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, pylint

I'm a newbie to Visual Studio Code and Python. I have this "import requests" line at the top of my helloworld.py. It clicked on the "Peek Problem" of the "import request", it shows the "Unable to import 'requests'pylint(import-error)". When I run the helloworld.py file in VSC, it shows this error.

> import requests
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'

I tried:
[image]

To isolate VSC, I tried import requests in Python3 interpreter and I got the same error.

[image]

By the way, I'm not using virtual environment. I have also looked at the following pages but I still couldn't get this error resolved.

- https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting#_specific-linters
- https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/1185
- https://donjayamanne.github.io/pythonVSCodeDocs/docs/troubleshooting_linting/
- https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1070423/How-to-import-REQUESTS-module-in-Python

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. Following these steps resolved my issue:

1. Look for python3 in the venv/bin folder of your current project. For me the path looked like this:

<kbd>/Users/your-user/this-vscode-project/.venv/bin/python3</kbd>

2. Now open the .vscode/settings.json. Now add this to the existing json:

<kbd>"python.pythonPath": "path from above"</kbd>

Save the code & Run it again!